# Assigning category permissions to users

Tags: users, category, permissions

Is there a way to assign category permissions to users so that they can only view/edit those categories?

I am currently looking at the following `getEditableSections()`, however, it's displaying all categories despite only assigning the user to a specific section. I have provided an example below:

Here's what I got:

**Section Alpha**
- Category A
- Category B
- Category C

**Section November**
- Category 1
- Category 2
- Category 3

Example: User John needs to access (view and edit) only Category B in Section Alpha.